# iteration collect char in C

Tags: c

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  int i,j,n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  n*=n;
  char str[n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    str[i]='*';
  }
  printf("%s",str);
  printf("\n%d",strlen(str));
  return 0;
}
```

I input 2 and this is the output I got:

```
2
****ú@
7
```

In line 2 it has some weird characters that show in console (U+0013 or control-S between ú and @), but it didn't show here.
Could you explain this to me?

Comment: This is missing code to add the `'\0'` terminator to `str` and hence invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `%zu` to print the length.  Use `%.*s` to print the string, but provide `n` as an argument before `str` to specify the maximum number of bytes to print.   Or null-terminate the string.  In fact, to use `strlen()`, you must null- terminate the array.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s", str)` assumes that `str` points to a NUL-terminated char array (aka "C string"). `str` is not NUL terminated in your case, so `printf` is running off the end of the buffer, resulting in undefined behavior.

To fix this you need to do two things:

- Allocate an additional byte for the NUL terminator
- NUL-terminate the array when you're finished writing to it

```
char str[n+1]
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    str[i]='*';
}
str[n] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing with `%s` format specifier which expects a C string(char array with NUL character at the end). You need to make the last character `\0` to make `printf` recognize the end of the string and stop printing. So allocate one more character in the array and set the last character to `\0`.

```
char str[n+1];
str[n] = '\0`;
```

Comment: Oh really I didn't know that, thanks for the clarification. I always wondered if there was a distinction in the terminlogy. Edit: So as I understand it is called  null character, abbreviated NUL, while NULL is just the c macro for (void*)0

Answer (score 0):

You need to NUL-terminate your string, like so:

```
char str[n+1];   /// <<<
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
  str[i]='*';
}
str[n]='\0';   /// <<<
```